# Does HTML date input use the same date format for value attribute in different regions?

Tags: html, input

I'm using an `<input type="date">` element. Can I assume that the value attribute always needs to be in the format: "yyyy-MM-dd"?

That is, regardless of the region/country that the browser is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The value attribute always has the format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, the presentation format is different depending on the user's locale. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/20057) for further details.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, David Walschots wrote in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/3745789):

> **Wire format** The HTML5 date input specification refers to the RFC3339 specification, which specifies a full-date format equal to:
>   yyyy-mm-dd. See section 5.6 of the RFC3339 specification for more
>   details. so if you want to set `max` or `min` you can use the format
>   `Y-m-d` for example **2000-01-01**
>
> **Presentation format** Browsers are unrestricted in how they present a date input. At the time of writing Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Opera
>   have date support (see here). They all display a date picker and
>   format the text in the input field.
>
> ... but inconsistently use slashes (30/01/2018) where for example dashes (30-01-2018) are expected by the locale's calendar format.

Comment: thanks - could you clarify what this means? "Yes, but inconsistently use slashes (30/01/2018) where for example dashes (30-01-2018) are expected by the locale's calendar format."

Comment: it means that it depends on browser, but they are all almost the same (but not exactly the same) they have a little bit difference.
so for readers there is no difference because reader can read it if it slash or dash, but in coding it different

Comment: @bnabriss you're not following the [rules on referencing material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Could you please adapt your answer?

Comment: @DavidWalschots , sorry for that, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @bnabriss you forgot to include the first bit. So I've edited your answer accordingly.